# Compile same source with diffrent aliases

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, alias, using

**TLDR:** Can you compile the same source code with different headers defining diffrent aliases?

I have created a library, with a set of functions coded using a couple of aliased type in the header.

`algorithm_2d.h`

```cpp
using Point = Eigen::Vector2d;
using Vector = Eigen::Vector2d;
```

`algorithm.cpp`

```cpp
Vector& scale_vector(
    Vector &v,
    double s)
{
    double len = v.norm();
    if (len != 0.0) { v *= s/len;}
    return v;
}

double distance_between_points(
    Point const &p1,
    Point const &p2)
{
    return (p2 - p1).norm();
}
```

Now I would like to compile the same `algorithm.cpp` but with different aliases:

`algorithm_3d.h`

```cpp
using Point = Eigen::Vector3d;
using Vector = Eigen::Vector3d;
```

I am building using `CMake` with `pybind11` as this is mainly a python library.

I would prefer not having to use templates, as that would cause me to have to define every single type in every function. And as you can see in the snippet, it would make it a lot less readable, and this is already a mathematically complicated algorithm (rest of the code not shown).

**EDIT:**

Another example to make it clear what I mean by using the aliases. If I were using templates, each time this function is called

`.h`

```cpp
using PointSet = std::vector<Point, Eigen::aligned_allocator<Point> >;
```

`.cpp`

```cpp
Vector compute_left_tangent(
    PointSet const &pts,
    int end,
{
    Vector tHat1 = PointSet[end+1] - PointSet[end];
    tHat1 = tHat / distance_between_points(PoinSet[end],PointSet[end+1]) 
}
```

I don't want to have to add the `<Eigen::Vector2d,..., etc>` every time I call one of these functions. Maybe there is a way of doing this with templates that I am missing?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a `template`.

Comment: You may control the necessary `#include` statements using `#ifdef` and an appropriate macro specified using the `-D` flag when compiling your `.cpp` file.

Comment: What do you mean by "have to define every single type in every function"?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to violate "One definition rule".

Comment: @Botje I have added an edit to try to explain it better

Comment: @MarekR It looks like I am... I think the solution is to modify the source file with cmake as  Botje suggested.

Comment: Your example under "EDIT" has lots of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following template file: (call it `algorithm.cpp.tmpl`)

```cpp
using Point = @_flavor@;
using Vector = @_flavor@;
#include "algorithm.cpp"
```

You can have CMake generate flavors automatically and build them as part of `some_target`:

```
set(FLAVORS Eigen::Vector2d Eigen::Vector3d)
foreach(_flavor ${FLAVORS})
  string(MAKE_C_IDENTIFIER ${_flavor} _flavor_slug)
  set(_flavor_out algorithm_${_flavor_slug}.cpp)
  configure_file(algorithm.cpp.tmpl ${_flavor_out} @ONLY)
  target_sources(some_target PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${_flavor_out})
endforeach()
```

Comment: Now that I see your edit, I'm not sure this is the correct solution... Are you aware that the C++ compiler can infer function template arguments from the actual arguments?

Comment: Yes, but some template definitions are not the same as taken by the arguments. eg: a function might take in a `Vector` but use `Point`, `PointSet`, and others inside its definition.

Comment: I should add that not all `Points` and `Vectors` will have the same underlying type, as is the case with `Eigen::Vector3d` here.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this is one use of compiler defines are for.

algorithm.h

```
 #ifdef 2D
    using Point = Eigen::Vector2d; using Vector = Eigen::Vector2d;
 #endif
 #ifdef 3D   
   using Point = Eigen::Vector3d; using Vector = Eigen::Vector3d;
 #endif
```

algorithm.cpp

```
Vector& scale_vector(
    Vector &v,
    double s) {
    double len = v.norm();
    if (len != 0.0) { v *= s/len;}
    return v; }

double distance_between_points(
    Point const &p1,
    Point const &p2) {
    return (p2 - p1).norm(); }
```

See also
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/conditional

Now you just need to tell your compiler to define 2D or 3D.

`g++ -D3D ...`

I think the microsoft compiler uses somtehing like
`/D3D`

Answer (score 0):

Template is your friend here. There are no problem you are so worry about:

> I would prefer not having to use templates, as that would cause me to
> have to define every single type in every function

And

> I don't want to have to add the <Eigen::Vector2d,..., etc> every time
> I call one of these functions.

[Template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) does all needed work here.

For example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
T& scale_vector(
    T& v,
    double s)
{
    double len = v.norm();
    if (len != 0.0) {
        v *= s / len;
    }
    return v;
}

template <typename T>
double distance_between_points(
    const T& p1,
    const T& p2)
{
    return (p2 - p1).norm();
}

template <typename T>
using PointSet = std::vector<T, Eigen::aligned_allocator<T>>;

template <typename T>
auto compute_left_tangent(
    PointSet<T> const& pts,
    int end)
{
    auto tHat1 = pts[end + 1] - pts[end];
    return tHat1 / distance_between_points(pts[end], pts[end + 1]);
}

void test_scale_vector()
{
    Eigen::Vector2d v2d { 1.2, 0.3 };
    scale_vector(v2d, 3.0);
    std::cout << "v2d:\n"
              << v2d << '\n';

    Eigen::Vector3d v3d { 1.2, 0.3, -0.22 };
    scale_vector(v3d, 3.0);
    std::cout << "\nv3d:\n"
              << v3d << '\n';
}

void test_distance_between_points()
{
    std::cout << "\ndistance 2d = " << distance_between_points(Eigen::Vector2d { 1.0, 2.0 }, { -1.0, -1.0 }) << '\n';
    std::cout << "distance 3d = " << distance_between_points(Eigen::Vector3d { 1.0, 2.0, 0.0 }, { -1.0, -1.0, -2.0 }) << '\n';
}

void test_compute_left_tangent()
{
    auto v2 = PointSet<Eigen::Vector2d> { { 1.0, -0.5 }, { 0.0, 0.0 }, { -1.5, 0.5 }, { -2.0, 2.0 } };
    std::cout << "\ncompute_left_tangent 2d:\n"
              << compute_left_tangent(v2, 1) << '\n';

    auto v3 = PointSet<Eigen::Vector3d> { { 1.0, -0.5, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }, { -1.5, 0.5, 0.2 }, { -2.0, 2.0, 0.5 } };
    std::cout << "\ncompute_left_tangent 3d:\n"
              << compute_left_tangent(v3, 1) << '\n';
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9sKxjvEod)

No code generators, no macros, no `#ifdef`s.

Or if you prefer to more restrictive templates definition  (so works only with Eigen): [this example works nicely too](https://godbolt.org/z/3rhPMac8o).

If you have any additional doubts please state them  in form of code which do not compile or do not run properly. You can start from my examples on godbolt provided above.

Comment: Yes but the issue is that Vector and Point might not be the same type of object. In  the case of R2 or R3 vectors and points are both represented by Eigen::Vectors. But more complicated objects like rotations have different definitions of vectors and rotations. 

So if the argument of the function takes in two points but does operations with vectors inside, I don't see how the Vector type can be deduced.

Comment: Please provide [mcve] which shows this is a problem. You can start from godbolt links I've provided. I do not see problems you are describing.